# how to make a marker follow user heading on mapquest

Tags: android, mapquest

I am developing a navigation app for Android using mapquest. An arrow represents my location on the map. Now, As Í start navigating, I want the arrow to change its heading dynamically according to the user's heading. Please help me out here

[How to rotate arrow head in googlemap v2 when we rotate the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826543/how-to-rotate-arrow-head-in-googlemap-v2-when-we-rotate-the-phone)

The link above answers a similar question for google maps. I would like to know the methods to do it in mapquest

Thanks